# How can I remove only small inner rings in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I am looking for a way to remove **small** inner rings in a large polygon.

I want to remove only the ones that are below a given surface and keep the bigger ones so that the the look (from a distance) is not affected too much.

If that could be done in a single SQL order, that would be great!

Comment: Do you mean "sliver", not "silver"?

Comment: No I mean silver, sorry about that, this is the Qgis terminoalogy ("Remove silver polygons"). I will rephrase my question with "inner rings" which is the term used in POSTGIS.

Comment: Its definitely "sliver" - QGIS has an "Eliminate sliver polygons" option!

Comment: @Spacedman, gosh! I have been using QGis on and off for 6 month and just realised that I always read that wrong. I think it is obvious English is not my mother tongue now (though I had a perfectly sound explanation for the "silver" name... wrong obviously)... Anyway, learnt something today.

Comment: There's a fantastic blog post on the subject here: http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/92/filtering-rings-in-polygon-postgis - I'd post as an answer but link-only answers are generally discouraged here...

Comment: At the first glance that is looking a bit above my current understanding, but I can probably manage creating teh function and using it.
Many thanks.
It you post this as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @Spacedman broken link :-(...

Comment: @giorgiomugnaini wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190416142725/http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/92/filtering-rings-in-polygon-postgis

Comment: @Spacedman thankyou for posting the wayback URL.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431682/14766

Answer (score 0):

Function code which filters small internal rings, removing those with area <= threshold argument

Source: https://www.spdba.com.au/filtering-rings-in-polygon-postgis/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Filter_Rings(geometry,float)
RETURNS geometry AS
$$
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(c.outer_ring, d.inner_rings) as final_geom
FROM (/* Get outer ring of polygon */
    SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(b.the_geom) as outer_ring
      FROM (SELECT (ST_DumpRings($1)).geom As the_geom, path(ST_DumpRings($1)) as path) b
      WHERE b.path[1] = 0 /* ie the outer ring */
   ) c,
  (/* Get all inner rings > a particular area */
   SELECT ST_Accum(ST_ExteriorRing(b.the_geom)) as inner_rings
     FROM (SELECT (ST_DumpRings($1)).geom As the_geom, path(ST_DumpRings($1)) as path) b
     WHERE b.path[1] > 0 /* ie not the outer ring */
       AND ST_Area(b.the_geom) > $2
   ) d
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: `ST_Accum` is obsolete.  Better to use `ST_Collect`.